# Como almacenar los datos de una variable local

Tags: python, funciones, bucles

tengo la siguiente duda. Si declaro una función donde se ejecuta una suma por ejemplo. Como podría almacenar los retornos de esa variable cada vez que la llame, voy a poner un ejemplo para explicarme mejor

```
def suma(a,b):
    resultado = a+b
    return(resultado)
```

Hasta ahí no tengo problema jaja, el problema llega cuando quiero llamar 10 veces la función y sumar todos los retornos algo así:

```
suma(5,10) # Me da 15
suma(1,2) # Me da 3
```

como podría almacenar en una variable el resultado, es decir almacenar en una variable 15+3

Algo como cada vez que llame la función suma se sumen los retornos

Comment: 2 opciones, utilizas una variable global o utilizas generadores `yield`

Comment: pensé en usar una función global pero no lo pude lograr, me podrías indicar como hacerlo?    Lo que hice fue declarar una variable global y entre la función suma la ponía a almacenar los datos con "+=" pero me saltaba un error

Comment: Pusiste global (tu variable global) al principio de la función suma cuando hiciste eso?

Comment: Ahora te doy la explicación

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres conservar una variable a través de sucesivas llamadas, puedes hacerlo agregando un atributo a la función.

Las funciones son objetos, y como cualquier objeto pueden tener atributos que son accesibles usando la notación `objeto.atributo` en cualquier otra parte del código.

```
def suma(a,b):
    if not hasattr(suma, "total"):
        setattr(suma, "total", 0)
    resultado = a+b
    suma.total += resultado
    return(resultado)
```

Primero preguntamos si `suma` (esto es, el objeto-función) tiene un atributo (campo) llamado `total` usando la función `hasattr`.

La función `setattr` hace dos cosas: revisa si el atributo existe en el objeto, y si no, lo crea. Lo segundo es asignar un valor a ese atributo.

Luego de eso, ya sabemos que el atributo existe, y podemos utilizarlo por la notación usual *objeto.atributo*

**Demo**

```
print(suma(5,10)) => 15
print(suma.total) => 15
print(suma(1,2)) => 3
print(suma.total) => 18
```

Comment: El ultimo `print(suma.total)` del demo dice que da 15 como si la suma no se hubiera hecho. No debería ser 18?

Comment: Copie mal el valor. Si ejecutas el código veras que da 18.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo con variables globales es tan facil como delarar la variable como `global` esto indica que puede ser accedida desde cualquier parte

```py
suma = 0
def sumar(a,b):
    global suma
    suma += a+b
    return suma

sumar(1,2)
sumar(2,2)

print(suma)
#salida->  7
```

Se declara como `global` dentro de la función por que de lo contrario se reemplazara con la variable `non-local` que hay dentro de ella y para que no nos de error de referencia al hacer `suma+=a+b` solo se inicializa con un valor de `0` al principio. Una cosa interesante es que el *scope* de una variable puede cambiar.